# How to delete in bulk for a Discord bot

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

```
import DiscordJS, { Channel, Intents, Message } from 'discord.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
const prefix = '~';

const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
  ]
})

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('The bot is ready')
})

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + 'clearall')) {
    async function clear() {
      message.delete();
      const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: 99});
      message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched);
      message.channel.send('Deleted 99 messages')
    }
    clear();
  }


})


client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

I'm trying to delete messages in a channel in bulk for a Discord bot, but I the clear() function, fetchMessages and bulkDelete comes out with errors.

[image]

Comment: For your first error, why are you making a named inner function? You can either make an IIFE or just make the origin function async.

Comment: Based on the documentation, [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel), it appears that you can't bulk delete messages in DM Channels (at least not with a function called `bulkDelete`, which doesn't exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Function declarations are not allowed inside blocks when targeting ES3 or ES5;

You can edit your `tsconfig.json` and set the `compilerOptions.target` option to something recent, like `ES2017` or even `esnext`. This is an interesing change since further errors can come because of targeting a legacy JS version.

If you still don't have a tsconfig in your project, create a file named `tsconfig.json` in the root of your project with something like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Since your code is going to run on a very recent JS version (inside node.js), there's no need to target an old JS version.

#### Extra: removing the unnecessary function

You also don't need to create that `clear()` function there. You can just run its inner code directly.

Removing the function will then trigger a warning about async await, which you can solve by changing this line:

```
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => { // add "async" there
```

#### x does not exist

The `channel` object does not have the `fetchMessages()` function. You can review the docs or CTRL+click to navigate the type definitions and try to find the desired function.

From a quick look it looks like `fetchMessages()` resides inside an inner `messages` object, so `message.channel.messages.fetchMessages(...)` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: for the .bulkDelete() function, you got any clues for that? I'm reading the TextChannel documentation for discord.js and I think it should work, but it keeps on saying "Property bulkDelete does not exist for text based channels"